# Install Powerpoint addin via script

Tags: vba, powerpoint, office-addins

I'm trying to install an addin to Powerpoint via any script. I found [this code](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWinGlue/0.3.1/Content/Scripts%5CInstall-ExcelAddin.ps1) but can anyone guide me how to run this script or create a bat file out of this. we have an installer, but that requires ppt to be closed and do not update to new version (uninstall existing addin and add new version of same addin) so everytime we have a new version of the addin, planning to trigger this script in user's machines during startup before ppt is opened.
Any other ideas welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

As long as PPT is not running, all you need to do to update an add-in is to copy the new version in, letting it replace the existing one.

You could, for example, use a startup BAT file that invokes XCOPY or ROBOCOPY to copy the PPA/PPAM file *only* if it's newer than the one already in place.

Note: this assumes that you're talking about a VBA add-in (PPA/PPAM). If it's a .NET add-in or some other type of COM add-in, this probably won't work

Comment: Thanks Steve. Yes its a ppam addin. I have created this bat file with xcopy and pasted to default addin location, with ppt closed. but when the next time ppt is opening, this addin is not loading in ppt. how to load this addin? my bat file code is: 

xcopy "C:\Zen\Zen Tools.ppam" "%AppData%\Microsoft\AddIns" /y /XO

Comment: @Jegan was the add-in already installed manually (I'd assume so) and if so, are you copying the new add-in file to the same folder/name as the installed add-in? Unlike Word/Excel, PPT won't automatically load add-ins it finds in a "magic" folder. You either need to set registry entries to load it at PPT startup or manually load it once then copy updates to the same location as the originally installed add-in.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Steve. yes, it updates if the addin is manually updated once and ppt is not running.

Comment: I have added reg entries but its not auto-loading for first time. In the location "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\PowerPoint\AddIns\ added ValueType: dword; ValueName: "AutoLoad"; ValueData: "1" and ValueType: string; ValueName: "Path"; ValueData: "%AppData%\Microsoft\AddIns\Zen Tools.ppam"

Comment: The reg entries belong in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\PowerPoint\AddIns\{ADDIN_NAME} (replace 16.0 with the appropriate value for your version). AutoLoad should be hex ffffffff, not 1. And you may have to supply the literal full path to the PPAM rather than starting with %AppData%. Not sure about that. In any case, as I suggested, this is easier if you manually load the add-in (from within PPT) and check the registry entries it makes.